# How to send images, audio, video stream using socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, communication

I have implemented a private chat system and public chat room for my website.

I would like to send send images, audio and video as well to get real time communication between users

WebRTC just seems to be out of my scope for now.

I need help regarding having communication(audio, images, video) using node.js and socket.io

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this tutorial as starting point to implement what you need  :
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js/